# Function Separation

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, matrix-decomposition, non-negative-matrix-factorization

I have a lot of measurements of a function $f(x,y)$ (lets say a lot more than a million measurements) at known values of the vectors x and y. The inputs to the function are the vectors x and y and the output is a scalar. I would want to find someway to express this function as $f(x,y)=g(x)\cdot q(y)$, where g(x) is a row vector of 5 elements and q(y) is a column vector of 5 elements and $\cdot$ indicates the dot product.

At present, we arbitrarily defined $g(x)$ and find the best $q(y)$ to match this arbitrarily defined $g(x)$. I do not want to arbitrarily define $g(x)$, I want to learn the best $g(x)$ to perform the separation. Non-negative matrix factorization does this if x or y is held constant and finds the ideal decomposition on the hyperplane defined by holding either x or y constant. I need the best decomposition on the entire space.